# Video player rotation in xamarin (Android)

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using MediaElement from xamarin community toolkit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/) and I need to rotate it. I'm trying to do this changing the rotation property:

```
<!--left:--> 
                <xct:MediaElement x:Name="vidLeft" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" IsLooping="True" Scale="2" ShowsPlaybackControls="False" />
<!-right:-->               
                <xct:MediaElement x:Name="vidRight" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" IsLooping="True" Scale="2" ShowsPlaybackControls="False" Rotation="90"/>
```

but it isn't working correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcDGA.jpg

So, any ideas how to do this?

By the way, I can use any other video player with video rotating feature.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the media file with Toolkit, there is something wrong with the Rotation property. And i do not find the official document for it.

For workaround, you could try to rotate the screen to rotate the media file.

You could rotate the screen with dependency service.

Create a interface:

```
 public interface IOrientationService
{
    void Landscape();
    void Portrait();
}
```

**Android:**

```
public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
public void Landscape()
{
    ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
}

public void Portrait()
{
    ((Activity)Forms.Context).RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}
}
```

**iOS:**

```
 public class OrientationService : IOrientationService
{
 public void Landscape()
{
    AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft), new NSString("orientation"));   
}

public void Portrait()
{
    AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
    appDelegate.allowRotation = true;

    UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber((int)UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait), new NSString("orientation"));
}
}
```

For the usage of dependency service, you could refer to the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

You could post the issue about the rotation of `MediaElement` in GitHub. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues